# How to schedule a test using JMeter for feauture test?

Tags: testing, automation, jmeter

I'm using JMeter for feature testing and i want to schedule a Jmeter test. Please help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling a JMeter test is something you have to do outside of JMeter, for example there are following options:

1. On Windows just go for [Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)
2. On Unix and derivatives like Linux there is [cron/crontab](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) or [systemd/Timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers)
3. On MacOS there is [launchd](https://www.launchd.info/)
4. Platform-independent: you can use a [Continuous Integration Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-vs-other-open-source-continuous-integration-servers/) in order to orchestrate your JMeter build(s). The most commonly used is [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) and it even has [Performance Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance) which allows you to conditionally fail the builds if monitored metrics are above/below thresholds, build performance trends basing on execution history, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but we would not use jenkins.